D compiler download / installation
I apparently need a D compiler for an installation of a cloud system. No D compiler found comes back. Where can I find a safe D compiler?

The same answer applies in Ubuntu for all versions of Ubuntu from 14.04 to the 24.10 development version, so I assume that one answer has got you covered for all of them unless you're running warty warthog  .

GNU D compiler, also known as gdc, provides the default D compiler based on the GCC backend in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. This compiler supports D language version 2.
To install gdc open the terminal and type:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdc build-essential

Once the installation is complete, you can verify it by running:
gdc -v

If you encounter any issues during compilation related to missing libraries or dependencies, consult the documentation for the specific cloud system you're installing.
